# Android App Dev db.query throw error source not found

Tags: android, sqlite

I have these 2 lines in which on second line cause error when debugging in eclipse ADT:

```
String[] tableColumns = new String[] {"_id","name","fruitId","vegeId","totalHours"};
Cursor cursor = db.query("PickingPeriod", tableColumns,"isDeleted = 0", null, null, null, "name" );
```

When I took "totalHours" out of tableColumns it works ok. It seems something to do with totalHours, but it is of the same type as fruitId and vegeId: INTEGER. Can **query** return more than 4 columns?

also When I changed to use rawquery it all works fine:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM PickingPeriod WHERE isDeleted = 0",null);
```

I read some suggestions that **query** is preferred over **rawquery**, therefore I'd like to get **query** working. Any idea what is wrong with the **query** lines?

thanks in advance

Comment: Check the spelling of totalHours and the one define in the table.

Comment: The column name totalHours has been copy-pasted throughout, and I have double checked the create table script and the mapping property in business class, all the same. Thanks anyway Hoan.

Comment: I have even renamed totalHours to hours for sake of simplicity, still no luck... super frustrating...

Comment: post your PickingPeriod table definition.

Comment: db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE PickingPeriod " +
    "(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
    "name TEXT NOT NULL, " +
    "fruitId INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
    "vegeId INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
    "totalHours INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
    "isDeleted INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0);");

Comment: I did not see the 0 inside the quote use Shajeel Afzal answer, or just put "isDeleted = " + 0. The answer below is the prefer way.

Comment: During debug I investigated the output of db.rawquery, apparently totalHours is not included in the returned columns. How could it be in the create table script but not selected when i call "Select *" ? Is there a way to force table to be recreated?

Comment: You probably add the columns after you already created the table, just uninstall your app and run again. It will be OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just want to share my fix here, it was definitely caused by the missing column totalHours in the table. It must have been added into the table after the database was created under the same db version 1. I learnt to trigger the database to be recreated by updating the database version to 2. When I re-loaded the enumerator the table was recreated with column totalHours, now everything works fine. Thanks all for trying to help. Hope my solution is helpful to other beginners.

However the remaining question to me is that I don't want to be forced to increase the db version number every time I want to recreate the database, especially while fixing bugs. Is it possible to modify the database without having to increase the db version?

Comment: Just delete the data though system settings or uninstall your app. These action will delete the database. The database onCreate is called only if it does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the 3rd argument `"isDeleted = 0"`, Try to change your code as follows:

`Cursor cursor = db.query("PickingPeriod", tableColumns,"isDeleted = ? " , new String[] { String.valueOf(0) }, null, null, "name" );`

You can read about the query method on the [Android Developer site.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: hi Shajeel, thanks for trying to help, but your suggested code shows error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from string to int.

Comment: Check it now. I am sorry that i quickly answered you and forgot to add `new` before `String[]` in the 4th argument.